# Criação de uma arquitetura Client-Server em C#

Tags: c#, .net, arquitetura-de-software, services, cliente-servidor

Fiz uma aplicação de teste em N camadas (acesso a Banco de Dados, apresentação, negócios (**model**) e objetos de transferência) funcionou tranquilamente e aprendi bastante sobre 3 camadas e N camadas.

Agora estou querendo fazer um programa que seja **cliente-server** e estou com estas dúvidas:

- Quando falamos em servidor a camada de negócios do sistema fica todo no servidor ou no cliente também, já que faço referencia a DLL de negócios na aplicação apresentação?
- Se a camada de negócios está inteira no servidor, como faço para ter acesso a ele no cliente?
- Para o *server* trabalhar também como serviço eu posso somente fazer uma aplicação console e pedir para instalar ou tenho que desenvolver como aplicação serviço?
- Se eu quiser separar também a camada de acesso a banco de dados, consigo manter persistente a conexão com o banco de dados? Minha ideia é construir uma aplicação que eu tenha a possibilidade de configurar qualquer banco de dados utilizando o ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quando falamos em servidor a camada de negócios do sistema fica todo no servidor ou no cliente também, já que faço referencia a DLL de negócios na aplicação apresentação?

Depende. Isto pode indicar que não fez as camadas tão bem assim. Uma parte fica no cliente, uma parte fica no servidor e uma parte fica em ambos.

> Se a camada de negócios está inteira no servidor, como faço para ter acesso a ele no cliente?

Não sei se entendi, mas não faz nada de especial, basta comunicar do jeito que resolveu fazer entre o cliente e o servidor, estabelecer critérios. Difícil responder assim de forma abstrata, tem uma quantidade de absurda de fazer isto.

> Para o *server* trabalhar também como serviço eu posso somente fazer uma aplicação console e pedir para instalar ou tenho que desenvolver como aplicação serviço?

Basicamente é isto, [veja](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas pode usar um *template* que já vem tudo configura para facilitar:

[image: Visual Studio com Windows Service template]

[Mais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

> Se eu quiser separar também a camada de acesso a banco de dados, consigo manter persistente a conexão com o banco de dados? Minha ideia é construir uma aplicação que eu tenha a possibilidade de configurar qualquer banco de dados utilizando o ODBC.

Sim, mas geralmente não é necessário, quase sempre esse monte de camada, generalização é idealismo e receita de bolo que não traz vantagem real, pelo contrário. Agora seria legal aprender fazer coisas mais simples que parece que está sendo mais difícil hoje em dia. Quando mais complexidade coloca na aplicação mais experiente precisa ser, mais precisa de de equipe, mais problemas arruma. Há casos que precisa, mas são raros.